# Handwritten signature comparison

Tags: java, comparison, signature

Does anyone know about a way in java to compare a handwritten text sample (e.g. a signature, autograph etc) to one or more samples? Preferably open-source?

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this [OCR Applet](http://www.heatonresearch.com/articles/42/page1.html).